# Specify loglevel for unit tests

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Does anybody know how to specify loglevel for unit tests and/or enable debug level log messages?

I'm writing\editing some unit tests for a class that extends DoFn in one of our pipelines.  One of the tests is failing in an interesting way and I'd like to capture the log messages (**including DEBUG**) to forward onto some other developers.

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.
I've tried a couple things

- First I added this to the VM arguments of the run configuration `-Dexec.args="--defaultWorkerLogLevel=DEBUG"`
- Second I created a resources folder under the src/test folder in my project then I put a log4j.xml in there that should enable debugg messages.

Just to answer the natural first quesiton, yes I'm pretty sure debug messages are disabled because I added this line to my unit test `System.out.println(String.valueOf(LOG.isDebugEnabled()));` and did see `false` printed in the console.

Thanks for any help,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for tests, you should be able to just adjust the log level of the JVM that you are running in. The `defaultWorkerLogLevel` only affects workers started up for distributed execution. The DirectRunner uses slf4j, so I believe you should look into adjusting the slf4j logging level, rather than log4j.